# Unable to convert a unicode data to float

Tags: python

I have downloaded a data set in xml format from online webpage. I have extracted the values tag using pattern library of python. This gives me unicode values.

I am looking to convert this unicode number, like u'63.3' to a float number. I have tried doing float(a) but it gives error messages.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pattern import web

xml = requests.get('http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1044.xml').text
dom = web.Element(xml)
values = dom.by_tag('value')

date= []
approve = []
disapprove = []

values = dom.by_tag('value')
for i in range(0,1724):
    date.append(pd.to_datetime(values[i].content))

for i in range(1724,3448):
    a = float(values[i].content)
    approve.append(a)

for i in range(3448,5172):
    a = float(values[i].content)
    disapprove.append(a)

finalresult = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'Approve': approve, 'Disapprove': disapprove})
finalresult
```

Output is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d9d9e580d883> in <module>()
      9 
     10 for i in range(1724,3448):
---> 11     a = float(values[i].content)
     12     result['Approve'].append(a)
     13 
    ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me... http://repl.it/LUj

Comment: `float(u'63.3')` does not give an error.

Comment: If you want a float, why would you try `int()`?

Comment: What error do you get when you try `float(a)`? What does `print repr(a)` print?

Comment: float(a) gives the following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

repr(a) prints u'63.3'

Comment: Can you try `float(str(a))`?

Comment: Is that a direct copy-and-paste of the output?

Comment: Your program works perfectly here, unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

It might be possible that one of your character (e.g. the ".") *looks like* the character you want to have, but in fact is an other one when checking the code table.

You can print all codes by writing

```
for c in a:
    print ord(c)
```

and compare the values you get with the unicode codepage. The decimal point should be 46 (`print ord(u'.')`), numbers should be in the range 48..57.

One other thought: Did you check the type of `a`? Maybe it's not a unicode object but something more complex. You could try `float(unicode(a))`, then.

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
float( u'63.3')
```

result:

```
63.3
```

Comment: The OP already stated that they have tried this... so why post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem seemed to be with the values in the 'value' tag field. The last 6 entries in the value tag under 'Approve' and 'Disapprove' were blank. So while trying to convert them to float the system gave an error. By adjusting the iteration to omit these values as below, the code ran fine. Keeping an eye on the entire data set and not generalising, was required in this case. Thanks all for the inputs.

```
#The last range number below is 1720 instead of 1727 as last 6 values of Approve & Disapprove tag are blank. 
for i in range(0,1720):
    date.append(pd.to_datetime(values[i].content))

#The last range number below is 3447 instead of 3454 as last 6 values are blank. Including till 3454 will give error while converting to float. 
for i in range(1727,3447):
    a = float(values[i].content)
    approve.append(a)

#The last range number below is 5174 instead of 5181 as last 6 values are blank.
for i in range(3454,5174):
    a = float(values[i].content)
    disapprove.append(a)
```